# Difference between assigning event handler to method with and without parentheses

Tags: javascript, function, event-handling

Assuming you have the following:

`function doStuff() {
  //code
}`

What is the the difference between the 2 statements ?

`window.onload = doStuff;`

`window.onload = doStuff();`

Both statements immediately called the method, but if I used the first statement, I could treat onload as a function pointer to "doStuff" and just call the method again using:

`onload();`

Is this the only difference, and in general, is this all guaranteed behavior for event handlers ?

Comment: Where did you get the idea that the first one immediately calls the method? It doesn't call the method until the window is loaded.

Comment: Sorry, my wording wasn't very good.
I know it's not immediate, but in terms of how many miliseconds it took for my page to load, I didn't think "immediate" was a poor choice of a word.
But you're right!

Comment: but that difference is critical. It may seem negligible to you, but it's an eternity to the computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually a bit off in your understanding.

```
window.onload = doStuff;
```

means that when the onload event is triggered, the doStuff function will be called.

```
window.onload = doStuff();
```

means that when that line of code is reached (before the onload event is triggered), doStuff is executed and it's return result is assigned to the onload handler.

You probably want the first one unless `doStuff` returns a function to be executed when the onload event is triggered.

Answer (score 3):

```
window.onload = doStuff();
```

This will fire immediately as the iterpreter get there.

```
window.onload = doStuff;
```

it's a reference to a function which future to be called.

Question :

When should I use `window.onload = doStuff();`

Answer:

When you need to create closure :

Example :

```
window.onload = doStuff();
```

Where

```
function doStuff()
    {
        var i = 0;
        return function ()
        {
            return i++;
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
window.onload = doStuff();
```

This executes doStuff() in straight away and assigns the function's return value to window.onload

```
window.onload = doStuff;
```

This assigns the actual function to window.onload. It assign it without executing it. doStuff will be executed when you call the load event.