# JavaScript Close Menu On Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm very new to JavaScript and having some trouble trying to get the desired result.  I've built an off-canvas menu based on the w3 school's example.  I want the user to be able to click the hamburger glyphicon to close the menu when it's open in addition to using the "x" button.  If there is an easier way to do this using JQuery that would be great as well!

Here's my attempt:

```
var width = document.getElementById("nav").style.width;
while (width != 0) {
    document.getElementById('glyphicon-menu-hamburger').onclick = closeNav();
  }
```

Here's the codepen:
https://codepen.io/nathanmathews/pen/XRKBBN

Here's my updated attempt, still incorrect:

```
var width = document.getElementById("nav").style.width;
if (width != 0) {
    document.getElementById('glyphicon-menu-hamburger').onclick = closeNav;
  }
```

Comment: Remove the `()`. For more information, read these [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20854084/difference-between-assigning-event-handler-to-method-with-and-without-parenthese).

Comment: That `while` loop condition doesn't make sense, because nothing inside the loop changes the value of the `width` variable.

Comment: Tried changing it to an if loop unsuccessfully.  How would I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `openNav()` with this `toggleNav()`

```
function toggleNav() {
  var nav = document.getElementById("nav"),
   main = document.getElementById("main");
  if (nav.style.width == "250px") {
    nav.style.width = "0";
    main.style.marginRight = "0";
  }
  else {
    nav.style.width = "250px";
    main.style.marginRight = "250px";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the updated code. Is this something you want ?

```js
function toggleMenu(){
  if($("#nav").width() > 0){
    closeNav();
  }else{
    openNav();
  }
}

function openNav() {
 $(".container-fluid .nav-menu span").attr("class","").html("×");   document.getElementById("nav").style.width = "250px";
     document.getElementById("main").style.marginRight = "250px";
}
    
function closeNav() {
  $(".container-fluid .nav-menu span").attr("class","glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger").html("");   document.getElementById("nav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginRight = "0";
}

var width = document.getElementById("nav").style.width;
while (width != 0) {
    document.getElementById('glyphicon-menu-hamburger').onclick = closeNav();
  }
```

```css
.nav-menu span{
  float: right;
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.nav-menu a{
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.hiddenNav{
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgb(164, 166, 168);
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 50px;
  transition: .5s; 
}
.hiddenNav a{
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s
}
.hiddenNav a:hover, .hiddenNav a:focus{
    color: #f1f1f1;
}
#main{
  transition: margin-right .5s;
}
.glyphicon-menu-hamburger{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!--Bootstrap-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--Main Wrapper-->
<div id="main">
  
<!--Navbar-->
<div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="nav-menu">
   <span onclick="toggleMenu()" class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Example</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<!--Hidden Menu-->
<div id="nav" class="hiddenNav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">Option 1</a>
  <a href="#">Option 2</a>
  <a href="#">Option 3</a>
  <a href="#">Option 4</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Another option but not exactly what I was looking for.  Works regardless, thanks!